# Not allowed to post because ' Body cannot contain "text" '

Tags: support, questions, content-blocklist

I'm trying to post a question about HTML and it keeps saying my first sentence isn't allowed. I've tried a number of different combinations of things, but with no success.

I have tried again after clearing cache, changing browser, logging in and out. Nothing resolved it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: how about "... I am working on ... " . Play with it

Comment: @Drew ive tried every possible sentence it gives me error everytime on the first same number of characters.

Comment: chunk is spelled wrong

Comment: @Crimson-Med Then remove these characters the message complains about.

Comment: @Drew Even corrected doesnt change anything.

Comment: It says don't have text Here is ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ ive tried changing to lots of different things even putting the link directly doesnt change anything

Comment: @Drew here you go: ![test 1](http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2016/18/1462499007-1.png) ![test 2](http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2016/18/1462499007-2.png) ![test 3](http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2016/18/1462499007-3.png) ![test 4](http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2016/18/1462499007-4.png)

Comment: I pointed a chat room to this. Maybe someone there knows

Comment: Just copy it all out, navigate away, and try asking again.

Comment: @Drew Thank you very much hope an answer will popup

Comment: @Laurel already tried that. Ive also tried different browsers and loging in and out

Comment: Laurel has a good idea. It may be a glitch. clipboard / try again

Comment: I don't suppose you could copy the text you are trying to post here, or make a pastebin and provide the link?

Comment: @Drew already tried.

Comment: @gunr2171 http://pastebin.com/M6DFtgAe

Comment: Create a new question with exact same kosher text from a good question of yours. Use a tag like `turtle-mock` temporarily. It is a uber low traffic tag. At the top of the question say something like "Please excuse this question for a few minutes, it is under construction." If that saves, fix the tags and the body with an edit. If that saves, one of us can help with an edit.

Comment: No, this is something for all users. I just tried to ask a question with the same text and I got the same error.

Comment: @Drew will try in a while i need wait 40 minutes now to post again. But apparently hichris123 gets the same error maybe someone should contact a webmaster?

Comment: @hichris123 good to know i'm not the only one

Comment: So it is identified as a bug. Thx hichris. Bug reports get upvotes. Just sayin' :)

Comment: @Drew lets hope so because -2 won't get much attention haha i'll keep trying some different things to try bypass the error

Comment: The issue is because there are too many non-latin characters in your post. If you remove every chinese symbol from your HTML, the warnings disappear. Why it's giving you the incorrect message, however, is beyond me.

Comment: The reason for the incorrect message is basically to make it more work for the (human) spammers who are the usual users of these characters on Stack Overflow, @Rob. Pointing directly at the bits of text they need to change sorta gives them an unfair advantage. I've added a slightly more descriptive error-message though.

Comment: @Rob thank you worked like a charm.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Get rid of the CJK text in your post. It's not *completely* blocked, but given SO is an English site and we've been hit by wave after wave of spammers posting CJK character-clogged posts, we disable posting non-trivial amounts of it.

Then fix all the stuff Nicol points out.

Then it'll probably work.

Comment: I removed the html code and this worked fine thank you very much i had no idea Chinese characters were filtered.

Comment: @Shog9: It sounds like the message for that filter needs improvement. Not to mention, the various Internationalization tags probably might want to use CJK characters.

Comment: @NicolBolas Already answered why the error message is currently so vague/inaccurate: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322508/not-allowed-to-post-because-body-cannot-contain-text#comment341321_322508

Comment: Yeah, I added some clarifying text to it, @Nicol. As for Int'l, you can have *some* of these characters, just not a lot; the intent is to discourage folks from writing large portions of their posts in languages that - to date - has mostly been used on SO to try & sell things to folks who aren't SO users.

Answer (score 6):

On the one hand, the stated reasons for rejecting your post seems dubious. On the other hand, all of your attempts are terribly written. You don't use capital letters, and other forms of grammar are at a minimum. Overall, your question is of poor quality.

So while the reasons for rejecting it seem wrong, that they are being rejected would appear to be a good thing. My guess is that you've run afoul of some filter, but the filter is incorrectly explaining the problem.

Comment: Ive tried even using eloquent language it doesn't change anything and another user has the same problem as well i just wrote some basic things to take the pictures faster but i could do some posh language screenshot if could help you think of a solution

Comment: It may not be the grammar that the filter is having a problem with. It may be the gigantic wall of HTML. It may be the fiddle. It may be a combination of factors. My point is two things: 1) your post seems to be blocked by a filter that can't explain the reason for blocking it correctly and 2) your post being blocked seems like a good thing for the site, so the filter's filtering part seems to be working fine.

Comment: I have tried posting just html and no jsfiddle no css, small html and jsfiddle no css, just css and jsfiddle, small html and css and jsfiddle. it gives me same error. I have also tried wrapping the table in a div but doesnt change much.