# Please introduce threshold to post documentation requests

Tags: feature-request, documentation, spam, documentation-proposals

We are receiving documentation requests from new Stack Overflow members with a reputation of 1 that look like this:

[image]

I ran this through Google Translate, and it's clearly SPAM.

Please, can someone raise the minimum required reputation for posting user requests? Otherwise we'll keep on getting these messages.

See the comment by TylerH: This is not a duplicate of [How to report users spamming in Documentation requests?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339215/how-to-report-users-spamming-in-documentation-requests). That is asking for a flag feature on doc requests. This is asking for a threshold on asking for doc requests to begin with.

Both questions are related, but mine was different. It received a different answer (which I accepted). I'm looking forward to the update of the question. Kudos to Shog9 and to Adam Lear for implementing the blacklisting functionality.

Comment: You know the excrement has hit the fan when the iText guy himself is complaining about it.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/339215/2675154

Comment: It's the horrible faux italic Chinese font that galls you most, right?

Comment: Actually, what galls me the most is that this is indistinguishable, quality-wise, from many of the submissions for the C++ tag documentation.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339215/how-to-report-users-spamming-in-documentation-requests. That is asking for a flag feature on doc requests. This is asking for a threshold on asking for doc requests to begin with.

Comment: @CodyGray Did you try running this through a C++ compiler?  It looks like it might actually be valid code.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Update:** These are now thoroughly blacklisted. If they figure out how to get past that, I'll blacklist them further. Kudos to Adam Lear for implementing the blacklist.

(detailed answer follows)

---

Well, we could.

Here's the breakdown of *actioned* topic requests grouped and sorted by the maximum privilege held by the requester:

```
Maximum Privilege    ActionedDtrs PctTotal        
-------------------- ------------ --------------- 
null                 158          5.154975530179  
Newbie               35           1.141924959216  
VoteUpMod            165          5.383360522022  
PostCommenting       77           2.512234910277  
Bounty               103          3.360522022838  
CommunityPostEditing 1343         43.817292006525 
PostEditing          250          8.156606851549  
CloseQuestion        472          15.399673735725 
ModerationTools      143          4.665579119086  
TrustedUser          319          10.407830342577
```

By "actioned" I mean "caused a topic to be created" (many more appear to have prompted the creation of drafts that never got approved). Here's the breakdown of **all** requests that weren't part of this spam wave:

```
Maximum Privilege    ActionedDtrs PctTotal        
-------------------- ------------ --------------- 
null                 712          9.55448201825   
Newbie               109          1.462694578636  
VoteUpMod            489          6.561996779388  
PostCommenting       246          3.30112721417   
Bounty               262          3.515834675254  
CommunityPostEditing 3325         44.618894256575 
PostEditing          530          7.112184648416  
CloseQuestion        934          12.533548040794 
ModerationTools      322          4.32098765432   
TrustedUser          523          7.018250134192
```

Slightly more on the low-end, but still over 90% of requests would do just fine if there was a 10-rep threshold for that privilege.

Now, just one problem: there's no actual privilege for this. I can't just crank up the threshold to 10 and be done; someone'd have to add logic to check against the privilege.

Meanwhile, these same spammers have been badgering Q&A for over a year; we've dealt with them by putting [a blacklist in place to block non-trivial amounts of CJK text.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322508/not-allowed-to-post-because-body-cannot-contain-text/322510#322510) For the past three days, I've been dealing with Docs spam by just periodically destroying anyone posting non-trivial amounts of CJK as a Topic Request; I've missed maybe a dozen requests because I'm only checking the title, but that leaves a false-negative rate of under 1% and a false-positive rate of 0.

So... If we're gonna make a change to restrict this, I'd rather go with the option that blocks zero actionable requests than the option that would've blocked even a handful of actionable requests.

FWIW, we added stricter rate-limiting for folks under 100 rep yesterday (1 request every 10 minutes) - that cut down the volume of spam a *lot*:

[image]

I'd kinda hoped they would just give up after that, but... No. Still creating new accounts, posting spam, getting destroyed.

Comment: Trivia: I've dismissed more spam requests in the past 2 days than all of the actioned requests ever created.

Comment: And I got SOCVR into a cleanup effort to dismiss over 900 spam requests in the JS documentation.

Comment: Ok, Adam's working on making this happen, I'm gonna go drink more coffee now so I can maybe proof-read @KevinL ;-P

Comment: @Shog9, Your actions and continuous diligence on this, and many other issues, are greatly appreciated by everyone. Thank you! [Well, OK, the spammers probably don't appreciate this most recent effort :-).]

Comment: Thanks @Makyen. And yes, they appear to have been very frustrated.