# Is all Documentation required to be in English?

Tags: support, documentation, languages

I've recently started getting more active in the review queues, and while SO Q&A appears to require English as its only language (one question was referred to the Portuguese site), I'm wondering if the Documentation sub-section has the same requirements.

I just recently rejected several changes because they were in an Asian language. Was I wrong to do that?

Comment: [There has recently been a rash](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339215/how-to-report-users-spamming-in-documentation-requests) of [spam submissions to Documentation in non-English languages](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339473/please-introduce-threshold-to-post-documentation-requests). Various attempts have been made to stem the tide, but perhaps they have broken through again. If you're still seeing them, links would be helpful so someone can look into it further.

Comment: I don't know how. I rejected several in a row with no interference. (I'm still learning review rules and periodically I get the "test" review.) So once I do that string of rejections I think the best I can do is what I did - post on meta (and yeah, still learning). Are you saying I should reject foreign languages as spam instead?

Comment: Just rejected several as "introduces spam", which seems a bit buried. Hope I did the right thing.

Comment: Here's an example - this is the best I can do for links, as they are pretty much dead to me after rejection: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/118353

Comment: All of the changes you review are actually tracked in your profile, and publicly visible. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/users/7014451/dfd?tab=documentation&sort=all). So I actually could have found these myself without asking you for links. Sorry. :-) Anyway, although you were the first person to alert Meta to the barrage of foreign-language spam being suggested to Documentation, you were not the only one. This has become a problem once again. Hopefully the Community Managers will take notice and step in. Yes, rejecting this as spam is the correct action. You're doing it right.

Comment: There are a lot of non-english changes being attempted on the `itext` tag over and over again. I've rejected dozens in the past few minutes. This is insane.

Comment: In general, posts should only be marked spam if they actually are spam. Simply being in another language doesn't constitute spam on it's own, so sometimes you may need to translate the text first. Otherwise, flag as unclear, or reject as not documentation. (In your case it was correct to mark as spam)

Comment: @4castle, I agree. But - being in another language is exactly what prompted my question. And yes, I'm not bilingual in any way, shape or form (my bad). So given that, what are you trying to say - in English :-)? Spam or not?I'm just trying to do this site right....

Comment: @dfd I'm not bilingual either. I'm just saying to toss the post into Google Translate or something and check if it's spam. If it's spam, then mark it as spam. If it's not spam, mark it as not documentation. If the user is repeatedly posting non-English things or you notice a large trend of users, then you can mark it as spam.

Comment: Posting unwanted foreign-language content to an obviously English-only website is one of many definitions for spam, @4cas. Besides, the penalties associated with spam that are perhaps giving you pause only apply to the spam flag for posts (questions and answers). This just a rejection reason for Documentation suggestions, and it works the same as any other rejection reason.

Comment: @4castle It's quite obvious an edit is spam if you see the same changes constantly under review, regardless of language. Even if the changes are programming related (This user wasn't even in that ballpark) I should never see the exact same changes twice, especially not twice in thirty seconds.

Comment: @4castle We also have precedent for SO being language specific: the quite active Portuguese SO https://pt.stackoverflow.com/ and others. Documentation should be even more strict about consistent primary language.

Comment: @CodyGray Wow, in that case I would say that Documentation is in desperate need for spam flag penalties.

Comment: @gelliott181 Right, I'm not saying to allow non-English posts to enter the system. I'm just suggesting a dichotomy of what rejection reason to use in the general case. (Not in the case of this user)

Comment: I am trilingual being my mother tongue not english and I'd rather have documentation in English. You don't know what a mess is trying to understand something from a coder that translates english words or concepts freely to his/her mother tongue. So allow non-english in documentation will corrupt the help and purpose Documentation brings to S.O.

Comment: As a Finn: yes f-n please

Comment: FYI those who are interested - Looks to be another crop of spammy submissions to the `itext'` tag (checked with Google translate and they do look to be actual spam, in Chinese) - Example - http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/120266

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Just like questions and answers on the Q&A site, Documentation *needs* to be in English. If it's successful, it will probably rolled out to the other Stack Overflow sites (Portuguese, Russian, etc.) as well.

Not only is content in other languages than English not useful for the Stack Overflow public, it is also harder to moderate.

Comment: So the proper thing is to reject. That's a good start. I was having a problem because of two things - (1) there were several in a row that I never expected to get to me, and (2) I thought the best rejection reason involved explicitly stating that English is need. It just seemed counter-intuitive if the rules were out there. Thanks for clearing things up for me.

Comment: Saying that "languages other than English are not useful" seems a bit strong. Certainly English is useful to more people, but that's not the same thing. Many SO users have a first language other than English.

Comment: @MichaelKay Languages other than English with a strong user base get their own SO site like http://pt.stackoverflow.com/. Documentation needs to be even more cohesive than the main site, so English only makes the most sense for the most users on the English "localized" site.

Comment: @MichaelKay: [SO is not all things to all people](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/07/non-english-question-policy/). The firm [English-only](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange), [delete-everything else](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297673/how-do-i-deal-with-non-english-content) policy isn't likely to change any time soon.

Comment: I wasn't objecting to the policy - I was objecting to the assertion that "content in languages other than English is not useful to the Stack Overflow public", which is blatantly untrue and smacks of xenophobia.