# Give "vandalism" and "copied content" rejection reasons Documentation bans

Tags: feature-request, documentation, spam, plagiarism

Recently, it came to my attention that [vandalism flags don't have more severe consequences](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340443/is-all-documentation-required-to-be-in-english?noredirect=1#comment426364_340443). In light of recent [issues with spam](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/339215/5743988) and ongoing issues with plagiarism, it would be nice if the community could stop spammers and plagiarists in their tracks before things escalate into minor chaos.

This would mirror the current system in Q&A, where a certain amount of flags for spam or rude/abusive causes automatic deletion and other consequences for the user.

I suggest that posting vandalism and plagiarism should be bannable offences (for a time period at least), and that the review queue should trigger these bans if used by a number of reviewers. Currently there [isn't a great system](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/34836376#34836376) for flagging major issues in Documentation.

[image: Vandalism and Copied Content rejections should be extra bad]

---

This post is very much in line with [this older question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/330001/5743988) from back when discussion about moderating Documentation was still in its [infancy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/330001/copied-content-should-have-automatic-consequences#comment375086_330001). Perhaps now we can make better decisions about how to moderate Docs.

Comment: If I could put a bounty on MSO posts...

Comment: Too many incorrect votes should also have consequences and help filter out additional crap

Comment: @charlietfl Perhaps, but posting incorrect information is a bit of a different beast. With the rejection reasons I've highlighted, users are intentionally doing these bad behaviors. There isn't really a precedent for banning based on knowledge of a topic on the Q&A, so I'm not sure about doing it on Docs or not.

Comment: Right, I'm not saying should be same criteria as blatantly malicious actions but at some point seems like someone who keeps posting rejected garbage should be at least notified

Comment: Maybe vandalism, but copied content is definitely not ban-worthy and is worded this way because of the fact that it's often unclear, subjective, and the result of honest mistakes, especially in the case of free/open sources, and common answers. Sometimes a code block has been passed along by dozens or even hundreds of different sources (blogs, Github, docs, SO answers), changed and tweaked along the way, etc, and someone may reasonably think that including that code or their version of it without attribution is fine, since it's public domain. Of course, they *should* give attribution though.

Comment: @Hack-R That's not the plagiarism that shows up in Documentation though. It's usually the entire article is copied and pasted.

Comment: I'm also basing the "copied content" inclusion based on the popular opinion in the [previous question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/330001/5743988).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the now deprecated feature of Stack Overflow Documentation.