# Code could not be submitted, because it triggered the spam filter

Tags: support, edits, spam

There is an issue with the code in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75865623/5211833) about extracting strings in Chinese in Python. If I attempt to edit the post to contain the code which the OP posted as [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75865623/why-is-regex-pattern-is-not-recognised-if-stored-in-an-object#comment133818803_75865623), this error/warning is displayed below the editing dialogue:

> Body cannot contain "".
>
> This appears to be spam. If you think we've made an error, make a post
> in meta.

And the system prevents saving the edit.

Is there a non-rendering character in that code? And why does this trigger the spam filter?

---

OP now edited the post with a slightly different code that doesn't trigger the filter. The original code still triggers the warning though.

Comment: The original code is no longer visible, the comment has been removed. We can't see what triggered it now.

Comment: @Mast the OP might have deleted them in that case. I hope a moderator can shed some light then, as they can see deleted comments.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Not allowed to post because ' Body cannot contain "text" '](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322508/not-allowed-to-post-because-body-cannot-contain-text). Too many Chinese characters and it will trip the spam filter.